# Python: How to create a reference to a sublist of a list? Is it even possible?

Tags: python, c++

Here's something that we can do in C/C++:

```
char *string = "mystring";
char *p = string + 2;
```

Now,

```
string = "mystring"
p = "string"
```

as they are both pointing to different location with in the same string.

Just wondering how can I do it in python. I can not do it using slice operator:

```
string = "mystring"
p = string[2:]  # will return a new string
```

Is there any way to create reference to a sub-string or point to a particular location then please let me know.

I don't want to store indices explicitly because that it's like delaying and calling a slice operator will again give me a new string.

Thanks!

Comment: Is this Python 2 or 3?

Comment: I think it would not be possible using built-in list. It's because the list data structure in Python is not simple continuous memory, which is different than C/C++.